# Can Inno Setup respond differently to a new install and an update?

Tags: inno-setup, upgrade

My InnoSetup script opens a web page (with the user's default browser) at the end of the install process:

```
[Run]
Filename: http://example.com; Flags: shellexec
```

However, I'd like the web page to *not* be opened if the app already exists, i.e., if the user is installing a new version of the program. The web page should *only* be opened after the initial install. (I assume it's worth mentioning that the install includes an AppID, obviously, and enters values in the registry beside installing files.)

Thank you, as always -- Al C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is easy to do with scripting.

Just write

```
[Run]
Filename: "http://example.com"; Flags: shellexec; Check: NotAnUpdate

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpInstalling then
    IsUpdate := FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\TheFileNameOfMyApp.exe'));
end;

function NotAnUpdate: Boolean;
begin
  result := not IsUpdate;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

*[The answer by @AndreasRejbrand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3205220/850848#3205283) won't work, if user chooses to install the executable to a different location than the last time.*

You can query installer-specific Inno Setup registry keys:

```
#define AppId "your-app-id"
#define SetupReg \
    "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" + AppId + "_is1"
#define SetupAppPathReg "Inno Setup: App Path"

[Setup]
AppId={#AppId}
...

[Run]
Filename: "https://www.example.com/"; Flags: shellexec; Check: not IsUpgrade
...
```

```pascal
[Code]

function IsUpgrade: Boolean;
var
  S: string;
begin
  Result :=
    RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, '{#SetupReg}', '{#SetupAppPathReg}', S) or
    RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, '{#SetupReg}', '{#SetupAppPathReg}', S);
end;
```

For an example how to use `IsUpgrade` in `[Code]` section, see
[Excludes part of Code section in ssPostInstall step if installation is update in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54808659/850848)

Check this if your "AppId" contains a left-curly-bracket:
[Checking if installation is fresh or upgrade does not work when AppId contains a curly bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54887002/850848)