# Excludes part of Code section in ssPostInstall step if installation is update in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I try to use same installer for both (fresh installation and update).

- so if user try to install my application for first time it will run the full installation included MySQL installer as prerequisites, and the part of MySQL  installation within `[Code]` will execute normally.
- but, if user already installed my application, and the installer is newer version (update), the part of MySQL installation within `[Code]` shouldn't be execute.

So, how to implement exception function for this part of code (MySQL  installation) if the installation is just updating?

```pascal
[Code]

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
{ ... }
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    { fresh installation code }
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IsUpgrade` function from my answer to
[Can Inno Setup respond differently to a new install and an update?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3205220/850848#28499259):

Though as it relies on a presence of "Uninstall" registry key, which already exists at the time of `ssPostInstall`, you have to cache its value.

```pascal
var
  IsUpgradeCached: Boolean;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  IsUpgradeCached := IsUpgrade;
  Result := True;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
{ ... }
begin
  if (CurStep = ssPostInstall) and (not IsUpgradeCached) then
  begin
    { fresh installation code }
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thank you @Martin Prikryl , Can i use "IsUpgarde" Function to skip database input page too, and use same function in [files] sections ?!

Comment: Sure, you can use it everywhere you need.

Comment: I try the solution as you describe above, but it didn't work, and I posted a new question in details here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56132550/10745484  @Martin Prikryl

Comment: OK, sorry, it does not work in `ssPostInstall`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: sorry for being late, i just had some issues in code, but after i solved it, your updated code run perfectly. @Martin Prikryl