# Checking if installation is fresh or upgrade does not work when AppId contains a curly bracket

Tags: inno-setup

I try to run same installer for fresh installation and upgrade.

In case it is an upgrade: some files and folders shouldn’t be copy and `server.bat` shouldn’t be run.
I use the function as it has been answered on the question ([Can Inno Setup respond differently to a new install and an update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205220/can-inno-setup-respond-differently-to-a-new-install-and-an-update#28499259)) and I used same `AppId` and defined the `#SetupReg` as it shown, and install the app for first time, and everything is good, but when I searched Setup Log I found that:

```
Line 122: 2019-02-27 15:46:13.797   Creating new uninstall key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{FDDFBC15-7B5C-4580-AD69-F54B8087A52E}_is1
```

Then I searched Registry and above path doesn’t exist, but I found the actually SetupReg path in

> HKLM\Softwares\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
>   {FDDFBC15-7B5C-4580-AD69-F54B8087A52E}_is1

I already defined it as script blow, the path in script was:

> HKLM\ Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" + AppId
>   + "_is1

I edit `MyApp.iss` and changed values of `MyAppVersion` to `"1.1.0"` and `VersionInfoVersion`  to `1.1.0`, and run installer again, I expected it will run an upgrade (files and folder which has `check: not IsUpgrade` shouldn’t copy or run) and it will disable installation directory page. But nothing expected happen.
The function `IsUpgrade` didn’t work successfully, files and folders which has `check: not IsUpgrade` have been copied normally and overwrote the old one, even the `server.bat` overwrote the old one and also run after installation finished.
What’s going wrong? Is it because of `#SetupReg` or `function IsUpgrade` or iss script?

```
#define MyAppName "Medfor"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0.0"
#define MyAppExeName "Medfor.exe"
#define AppId "{{FDDFBC15-7B5C-4580-AD69-F54B8087A52E}"
#define SetupReg "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" + AppId + "_is1"
#define SetupAppPathReg "Inno Setup: App Path"

[Setup]
AppId={#AppId}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}

[Files]
Source: "build\server.bat"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Check: not IsUpgrade

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\server.bat"; \
    Flags: postinstall skipifsilent runascurrentuser waituntilterminated; \
    Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; \
    Check: not IsUpgrade
```

```pascal
[Code]
function IsUpgrade: Boolean;
var
  S: string;
begin
  Result :=
    RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, '{#SetupReg}', '{#SetupAppPathReg}', S) or
    RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, '{#SetupReg}', '{#SetupAppPathReg}', S);
end;
```

First Installation Log:

```
2019-02-27 15:45:48.996   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC+03:00)
2019-02-27 15:45:48.996   Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.6.1 (a)
2019-02-27 15:45:48.996   Original Setup EXE: C:\Users\user\Documents\Output\Medfor-setup.exe
2019-02-27 15:45:48.996   Setup command line: /SL5="$2307BA,9890028,58368,C:\Users\user\Documents\Output\Medfor-setup.exe" /SPAWNWND=$2B04B6 /NOTIFYWND=$390B4C 
2019-02-27 15:45:48.997   Windows version: 6.3.9600  (NT platform: Yes)
2019-02-27 15:45:48.997   64-bit Windows: Yes
2019-02-27 15:45:48.997   Processor architecture: x64
2019-02-27 15:45:48.997   User privileges: Administrative
2019-02-27 15:45:48.999   64-bit install mode: No
2019-02-27 15:45:49.004   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\is-IH9A3.tmp
2019-02-27 15:46:11.561   Starting the installation process.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.690   Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor
2019-02-27 15:46:11.690   Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\App
2019-02-27 15:46:11.691   Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\App\sections
2019-02-27 15:46:11.691   Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\App\sections\templates_sections
2019-02-27 15:46:11.691   Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\App\sections\templates_sections\headers
2019-02-27 15:46:11.692   Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\App\sections\templates_sections\modals
2019-02-27 15:46:11.693   Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\App\templates
2019-02-27 15:46:11.693   Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\App\templates\errors
2019-02-27 15:46:11.694   Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\App\templates\menus
2019-02-27 15:46:11.694   Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\App\templates\modals
2019-02-27 15:46:11.695   Creating directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\Uploads
2019-02-27 15:46:11.696   Directory for uninstall files: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor
2019-02-27 15:46:11.696   Creating new uninstall log: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\unins000.dat
2019-02-27 15:46:11.701   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:11.702   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\unins000.exe
2019-02-27 15:46:11.705   Time stamp of our file: 2019-02-27 15:45:48.834
2019-02-27 15:46:11.705   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.719   Uninstaller requires administrator: Yes
2019-02-27 15:46:11.720   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.721   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:11.722   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\mfcm90u.dll
2019-02-27 15:46:11.722   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:14.000
2019-02-27 15:46:11.723   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.731   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.731   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:11.732   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
2019-02-27 15:46:11.733   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:08.000
2019-02-27 15:46:11.733   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.735   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.736   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:11.737   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\Microsoft.VC90.MFC.manifest
2019-02-27 15:46:11.738   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:14.000
2019-02-27 15:46:11.738   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.741   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.741   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:11.743   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\msvcm90.dll
2019-02-27 15:46:11.743   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:08.000
2019-02-27 15:46:11.743   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.766   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.766   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:11.767   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\msvcp90.dll
2019-02-27 15:46:11.768   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:08.000
2019-02-27 15:46:11.768   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.837   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.837   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:11.839   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\msvcr90.dll
2019-02-27 15:46:11.839   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:08.000
2019-02-27 15:46:11.839   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.913   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.914   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:11.914   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\service.bat
2019-02-27 15:46:11.915   Time stamp of our file: 2018-12-16 16:53:52.000
2019-02-27 15:46:11.915   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.917   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:11.917   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:11.918   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\sqlite3.dll
2019-02-27 15:46:11.918   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:26.000
2019-02-27 15:46:11.918   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:12.012   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:12.012   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:12.013   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\tcl85.dll
2019-02-27 15:46:12.013   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:26.000
2019-02-27 15:46:12.013   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:12.143   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:12.143   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:12.145   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\medfor.dll
2019-02-27 15:46:12.145   Time stamp of our file: 2019-02-27 13:15:42.000
2019-02-27 15:46:12.145   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:12.148   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:12.149   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:12.149   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\Medfor.exe
2019-02-27 15:46:12.150   Time stamp of our file: 2018-10-29 02:05:20.000
2019-02-27 15:46:12.150   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:12.790   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:12.791   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:12.791   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\mfc90.dll
2019-02-27 15:46:12.792   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:14.000
2019-02-27 15:46:12.792   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.287   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.287   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:13.288   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\mfc90u.dll
2019-02-27 15:46:13.288   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:14.000
2019-02-27 15:46:13.288   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.541   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.541   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:13.542   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\mfcm90.dll
2019-02-27 15:46:13.542   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:14.000
2019-02-27 15:46:13.542   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.549   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.549   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:13.550   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\App\templates\errors\403.html
2019-02-27 15:46:13.550   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-21 16:21:04.000
2019-02-27 15:46:13.550   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.552   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.552   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:13.553   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\App\templates\errors\404.html
2019-02-27 15:46:13.553   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-21 16:21:04.000
2019-02-27 15:46:13.553   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.555   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.555   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:13.556   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\Uploads\Capture.gif
2019-02-27 15:46:13.557   Time stamp of our file: 2018-07-31 21:51:14.000
2019-02-27 15:46:13.557   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.565   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.566   -- Icon entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:13.566   Dest filename: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Medfor.lnk
2019-02-27 15:46:13.568   Creating the icon.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.794   Successfully created the icon.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.797   Saving uninstall information.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.797   Deleting any uninstall keys left over from previous installs
2019-02-27 15:46:13.797   Creating new uninstall key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{FDDFBC15-7B5C-4580-AD69-F54B8087A52E}_is1
2019-02-27 15:46:13.797   Writing uninstall key values.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.961   Installation process succeeded.
2019-02-27 15:46:13.963   Need to restart Windows? No
2019-02-27 15:46:21.260   -- Run entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:21.260   Run as: Current user
2019-02-27 15:46:21.260   Type: Exec
2019-02-27 15:46:21.260   Filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\service.bat
2019-02-27 15:46:27.225   Process exit code: 1
2019-02-27 15:46:27.225   -- Run entry --
2019-02-27 15:46:27.225   Run as: Original user
2019-02-27 15:46:27.225   Type: Exec
2019-02-27 15:46:27.225   Filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\Medfor.exe
```

Second Installation Log (Expected Upgrade)

```
2019-02-27 16:42:48.069   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC+03:00)
2019-02-27 16:42:48.070   Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.6.1 (a)
2019-02-27 16:42:48.070   Original Setup EXE: C:\Users\user\Documents\Output\Medfor-1.1.0-setup.exe
2019-02-27 16:42:48.070   Setup command line: /SL5="$4A052C,9889159,58368,C:\Users\user\Documents\Output\Medfor-1.1.0-setup.exe" /SPAWNWND=$9C0140 /NOTIFYWND=$5F02BC 
2019-02-27 16:42:48.070   Windows version: 6.3.9600  (NT platform: Yes)
2019-02-27 16:42:48.070   64-bit Windows: Yes
2019-02-27 16:42:48.071   Processor architecture: x64
2019-02-27 16:42:48.071   User privileges: Administrative
2019-02-27 16:42:48.074   64-bit install mode: No
2019-02-27 16:42:48.082   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\is-Q7EVG.tmp
2019-02-27 16:43:13.652   Starting the installation process.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.662   Directory for uninstall files: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor
2019-02-27 16:43:13.662   Will append to existing uninstall log: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\unins000.dat
2019-02-27 16:43:13.668   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:13.669   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\unins000.exe
2019-02-27 16:43:13.673   Time stamp of our file: 2019-02-27 16:42:47.947
2019-02-27 16:43:13.673   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.673   Time stamp of existing file: 2019-02-27 15:45:48.834
2019-02-27 16:43:13.673   Version of our file: 51.52.0.0
2019-02-27 16:43:13.674   Version of existing file: 51.52.0.0
2019-02-27 16:43:13.674   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.700   Uninstaller requires administrator: Yes
2019-02-27 16:43:13.700   Leaving temporary file in place for now.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.701   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:13.703   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\mfcm90u.dll
2019-02-27 16:43:13.703   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:14.000
2019-02-27 16:43:13.703   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.703   Time stamp of existing file: 2018-11-25 14:38:14.000
2019-02-27 16:43:13.704   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.716   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.716   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:13.718   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest
2019-02-27 16:43:13.719   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:08.000
2019-02-27 16:43:13.719   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.719   Time stamp of existing file: 2018-11-25 14:38:08.000
2019-02-27 16:43:13.719   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.724   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.725   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:13.727   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\Microsoft.VC90.MFC.manifest
2019-02-27 16:43:13.728   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:14.000
2019-02-27 16:43:13.728   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.728   Time stamp of existing file: 2018-11-25 14:38:14.000
2019-02-27 16:43:13.728   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.733   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.734   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:13.735   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\msvcm90.dll
2019-02-27 16:43:13.736   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:08.000
2019-02-27 16:43:13.736   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.736   Time stamp of existing file: 2018-11-25 14:38:08.000
2019-02-27 16:43:13.736   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.770   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.771   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:13.773   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\msvcp90.dll
2019-02-27 16:43:13.773   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:08.000
2019-02-27 16:43:13.774   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.774   Time stamp of existing file: 2018-11-25 14:38:08.000
2019-02-27 16:43:13.774   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.870   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.871   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:13.872   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\msvcr90.dll
2019-02-27 16:43:13.873   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:08.000
2019-02-27 16:43:13.873   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.873   Time stamp of existing file: 2018-11-25 14:38:08.000
2019-02-27 16:43:13.873   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.977   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.978   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:13.980   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\server.bat
2019-02-27 16:43:13.981   Time stamp of our file: 2019-02-27 16:37:22.000
2019-02-27 16:43:13.981   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.981   Time stamp of existing file: 2019-02-27 16:40:59.984
2019-02-27 16:43:13.981   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.985   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.986   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:13.987   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\sqlite3.dll
2019-02-27 16:43:13.988   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:26.000
2019-02-27 16:43:13.988   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:13.988   Time stamp of existing file: 2018-11-25 14:38:26.000
2019-02-27 16:43:13.988   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:14.159   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:14.193   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:14.194   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\tcl85.dll
2019-02-27 16:43:14.195   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:26.000
2019-02-27 16:43:14.195   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:14.195   Time stamp of existing file: 2018-11-25 14:38:26.000
2019-02-27 16:43:14.195   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:14.421   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:14.422   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:14.424   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\medfor.dll
2019-02-27 16:43:14.424   Time stamp of our file: 2019-02-27 13:15:42.000
2019-02-27 16:43:14.425   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:14.425   Time stamp of existing file: 2019-02-27 13:15:42.000
2019-02-27 16:43:14.425   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:14.431   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:14.431   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:14.433   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\Medfor.exe
2019-02-27 16:43:14.434   Time stamp of our file: 2018-10-29 02:05:20.000
2019-02-27 16:43:14.434   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:14.434   Time stamp of existing file: 2018-10-29 02:05:20.000
2019-02-27 16:43:14.434   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:15.386   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:15.387   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:15.388   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\mfc90.dll
2019-02-27 16:43:15.389   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:14.000
2019-02-27 16:43:15.389   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:15.389   Time stamp of existing file: 2018-11-25 14:38:14.000
2019-02-27 16:43:15.389   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.087   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.088   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:16.089   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\mfc90u.dll
2019-02-27 16:43:16.089   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:14.000
2019-02-27 16:43:16.089   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.089   Time stamp of existing file: 2018-11-25 14:38:14.000
2019-02-27 16:43:16.090   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.432   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.432   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:16.434   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\mfcm90.dll
2019-02-27 16:43:16.435   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-25 14:38:14.000
2019-02-27 16:43:16.435   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.435   Time stamp of existing file: 2018-11-25 14:38:14.000
2019-02-27 16:43:16.435   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.450   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.450   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:16.451   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\App\templates\errors\403.html
2019-02-27 16:43:16.452   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-21 16:21:04.000
2019-02-27 16:43:16.452   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.452   Time stamp of existing file: 2018-11-21 16:21:04.000
2019-02-27 16:43:16.452   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.455   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.456   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:16.457   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\App\templates\errors\404.html
2019-02-27 16:43:16.457   Time stamp of our file: 2018-11-21 16:21:04.000
2019-02-27 16:43:16.457   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.457   Time stamp of existing file: 2018-11-21 16:21:04.000
2019-02-27 16:43:16.457   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.460   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.460   -- File entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:16.461   Dest filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\Uploads\Capture.gif
2019-02-27 16:43:16.462   Time stamp of our file: 2018-07-31 21:51:14.000
2019-02-27 16:43:16.462   Dest file exists.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.462   Time stamp of existing file: 2018-07-31 21:51:14.000
2019-02-27 16:43:16.462   Installing the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.478   Successfully installed the file.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.480   -- Icon entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:16.480   Dest filename: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Medfor.lnk
2019-02-27 16:43:16.483   Creating the icon.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.630   Successfully created the icon.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.634   Saving uninstall information.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.634   Renaming uninstaller.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.635   Deleting any uninstall keys left over from previous installs
2019-02-27 16:43:16.636   Creating new uninstall key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{FDDFBC15-7B5C-4580-AD69-F54B8087A52E}_is1
2019-02-27 16:43:16.637   Writing uninstall key values.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.828   Installation process succeeded.
2019-02-27 16:43:16.830   Need to restart Windows? No
2019-02-27 16:43:21.677   -- Run entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:21.677   Run as: Current user
2019-02-27 16:43:21.677   Type: Exec
2019-02-27 16:43:21.677   Filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\server.bat
2019-02-27 16:43:22.055   Process exit code: 0
2019-02-27 16:43:22.055   -- Run entry --
2019-02-27 16:43:22.055   Run as: Original user
2019-02-27 16:43:22.055   Type: Exec
2019-02-27 16:43:22.055   Filename: C:\Program Files (x86)\Medfor\Medfor.exe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your "AddId" is `{xxx}`, not `{{xxx}` (check the registry key path in your question). The double curly bracket is needed in [`AppId` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appid), as in Inno Setup directives a curly bracket have a special meaning (for [constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts)). If you want to use a curly bracket literally, you have to double it.

But in Pascal Script code, a curly bracket has no special meaning. So if you use two, your Pascal Script code will explicitly look for `{{xxx}` in the registry. And naturally, it won't find it there, as there's `{xxx}`.

One way to solve this (without duplicating `xxx` between the directive and the code) is by doubling the curly bracket using preprocessor in the `AppId` directive only:

```
#define AppId "{FDDFBC15-7B5C-4580-AD69-F54B8087A52E}"
; One curly bracket for Pascal Script code
#define SetupReg "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" + AppId + "_is1"

[Setup]
; Two curly brackets for directive
AppId={#StringChange(AppId, '{', '{{')}
```