# How can I make default a checkmark in the line "Don't create a Start Menu folder" -Inno Setup-

Tags: inno-setup

I use Inno Setup as *extractor* for my Portable software (Windows). I want in the line "Do not create a Start Menu folder" to be checked by **default**, so that if the user wants a folder in the start menu he must **uncheck** the check box.
Thanks for your time and help,
Alexei

Answer (score 0):

Programatically check the respective checkbox component (`WizardForm.NoIconsCheck`).

You should do it on fresh installs only. For upgrades/reinstalls, you should keep the previous user selection (more so, now that Inno Setup does not even show the *Select Start Menu Folder* wizard page for reinstalls).

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  if not IsUpgrade then
    WizardForm.NoIconsCheck.Checked := True;
end;
```

For the `IsUpgrade` function, see my answer to
[Can Inno Setup respond differently to a new install and an update?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3205220/850848#28499259)